ubuntu 24.04 install usb key altering itself during install?
My Ubuntu Desktop 24.04.1 installation usb key seems to have altered its own content during installation. any explanation?
(observation probably explained by my comment below)
i've done this:
(/dev/sdc is a 60GB usb key)

On PC 1:

download ubuntu-24.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
cat ubuntu-24.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso > /dev/sdc
check usb key using head -c 6203355136 /dev/sdc | sha256sum (result correct, like on the web: c2e6f4dc37ac944e2ed507f87c6188dd4d3179bf4a3f9e110d3c88d1f3294bdc)


On PC 2:

install ubuntu to PC 2 using the prepared installation usb key


On PC 1:

check usb key using head -c 6203355136 /dev/sdc | sha256sum (result changed to this: 72b03bd3af8d0eb75f6ac8b9eecf8dba8f39378068e3a63ef6eb0fee649ab726)



I then checked for the first difference. it's within the first 512 bytes of the usb key. here is the comparison of these 512 bytes. left is original iso image, right is the changed usb key:

Do you have any idea why this happens? I'm surprised to see an altered installation image on a usb key. IMHO, this should not happen.
Update1:
Here is the complete diff of the hexdumps of the original iso image and the content of the usb key (the first 6203355136 bytes of it):
$ diff _orig_ub_iso_hd _dev_sdc_hd
29c29
< 000001c0  02 00 ee 3f e0 ff 01 00  00 00 d7 df b8 00 80 00  |...?............|
---
> 000001c0  02 00 ee ff ff ff 01 00  00 00 ff ff 4d 07 80 00  |............M...|
34,36c34,36
< 00000210  72 e3 13 89 00 00 00 00  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |r...............|
< 00000220  d7 df b8 00 00 00 00 00  40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |........@.......|
< 00000230  98 df b8 00 00 00 00 00  8a de d3 ee d3 ac 41 45  |..............AE|
---
> 00000210  b1 7d d6 da 00 00 00 00  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.}..............|
> 00000220  ff ff 4d 07 00 00 00 00  40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |..M.....@.......|
> 00000230  c0 ff 4d 07 00 00 00 00  8a de d3 ee d3 ac 41 45  |..M...........AE|
38c38
< 00000250  f8 00 00 00 80 00 00 00  3d e3 06 8a 00 00 00 00  |........=.......|
---
> 00000250  f8 00 00 00 80 00 00 00  aa 1a e8 06 00 00 00 00  |................|
59a60,64
> *
> 00000580  af 3d c6 0f 83 84 72 47  8e 79 3d 69 d8 47 7d e4  |.=....rG.y=i.G}.|
> 00000590  05 2f 96 23 fa ba 01 4c  a6 b3 1e f1 5f d5 b2 08  |./.#...L...._...|
> 000005a0  00 e0 b8 00 00 00 00 00  ff f7 4d 07 00 00 00 00  |..........M.....|
> 000005b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|

As you can see, there are only a few differences and they're all in the first 2KB of data.

I suspect that this has to do with install-logs, which are automatically written to another partition on the usb key. My theory: Another partition is added automatically by the installer and the partition tables in the MBR are adjusted to reflect this, hence the change near the front of the data.
